# How to obtain Clang on Cygwin

Tags: clang, cygwin, llvm, clang++

I have installed Cygwin, but I didn't see Clang or LLVM in the list of Cygwin installation packages when choosing `devel`, `GCC`, `GDB` etc.

How do I install Clang on Cygwin? I want to use it for compiling C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLang is available from setup:
be sure to be connected to internet and not using local cache.
Use the `Full` view. You can use the search to reduce the number of packages

[image]

Comment: How did you provide libstdc++ path to clang.

Comment: The clang which comes with installation package is very outdated. The current latest version is V14, while above is only V8. Do you know how to get the latest clang on cygwin? Thanks

Comment: Currently the package is missing a maintainer as such there is no plan short term to update it. Compilers are usually resource/effort  intensive packages and volunteer are very scarce  https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/clang-src.html